# Calling save on a destroyed object returns true, but doesn't save

Tags: ruby, mongoid

Getting weird behavior when trying to save a Mongoid object that has been previously destroyed.  Given this class definition:

```
class Foo
  include Mongoid::Document
end
```

After saving an instance, then deleting it, I am unable to save again:

```
Foo.count # => 0
f = Foo.create # => #<Foo _id: 522744a78d46b9b09f000001, >
Foo.count # => 1
f.destroy # => true
Foo.count # => 0
f.save # => true
# it lied - didn't actually save:
Foo.count # => 0
# these may be relevant:
f.persisted? # => false
f.destroyed? # => true
f.new_record? # => false
f.changed? # => false
```

Here's a failing RSpec test that I would expect to pass:

```
describe Foo do
  it 'should allow saving a Foo instance after destroying it' do
    expect(Foo.count).to eq(0)
    f = Foo.create
    expect(Foo.count).to eq(1)
    Foo.all.destroy
    expect(Foo.count).to eq(0)
    f.save # => true
    expect(Foo.count).to eq(1) # error - returns 0
  end
end
```

Is this expected behavior?  My use case is actually using a singleton object (didn't want to make the question more complicated by mentioning it though); `Foo.instance` returns the same object that was destroyed by `Foo.all.destroy` which is gumming up things.

Comment: Try cloning the destroyed object and send save message to it.

Comment: The thing is that rails freezes the object once you destroy it. So, you wont be able to further save it. So, clone is is rescue.

Comment: As I mentioned at the bottom of the question, my real use case is a [singleton](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/singleton/rdoc/Singleton.html), which doesn't allow cloning or duping.  You're right though, AFAIK Mongoid does try to follow the ActiveModel interface so perhaps this is expected behavior from that (and ActiveRecord would exhibit the same behavior?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Model#save**
>
> Saves the changed attributes to the database atomically, or insert the document if new. Will raise an error of validations fail.

After destruction, the document is not new and there are no attributes that have changed, so `save` just returns without errors. In a strict sense this seems to be the expected behavior.

You could use [`Model#upsert`](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/persistence.html):

> Performs a MongoDB `upsert` on the document. If the document exists in the database, it will get overwritten with the current attributes of the document in memory. If the document does not exist in the database, it will be inserted.

This will actually save the document using the same ID, but it will still be `frozen?` and marked as `destroyed?`. Therefore it might be better to just `clone` the document as suggested by insane-36 in the comments.